# Can light be one of the causes for the expansion of universe?

Tags: visible-light, cosmology, universe, big-bang

first of all, is the universse infinite or finite?

If finite, then the universe is itself expanding, so if you assume the farthest star in the farthest galaxy emits light. The photon would be able to reach the edge of universe and then what would happen to it would it? Would it travel out and be the cause of expansion or would something else would happen to it.

If Universe is infinite -
then I am sorry to ask the question, because light would never be able to reach the edge.

Comment: What does "outside the universe" mean?

Comment: I have clarified myself in the body now for your review .....

Comment: Edited the question too...

Comment: Your question is unclear. Why and how would light be the cause of expansion?

Comment: Do you mean the apparent energy loss when light travels through space?

Comment: Added in the body something more......

Comment: @physics2000 as far as i can tell, the question assumes the universe is finite, then states it is expanding, asking if light "hitting" the boundary causes it to expand

Comment: @Cursed but the light cannot reach this ‘boundary’ as this boundary is backwards in time.

Comment: @physics2000 thats the question. don't shoot the messenger

Comment: @Cursed but we know the most probable reason is dark energy

Comment: @Cursed you understood what I wanted to ask.

Comment: @physics2000 can you explain me what is meant by "boundary is backwards in time"

Comment: @C.Jain well look. As I told you in my answer the universe expanded faster than light could. Since light could travel at a finite speed it was slower than the expansion of the universe. That means the most distant stars that we can see, we see them when they were older in time. That means the most distant we can see is when light formed as a result of atoms. Hence you see the boundary is backwards in time

Comment: Well you see the problem is that gravity is unavoidable at the large scale level. Considering the amount of mass you would need so much of energy in order to push this ‘boundary’(according to you question) even gamma rays may be unable to do it. It would have a energy of 15 X 10^(-11) joules. Considering the amount of matter only in the observable universe , do you really think that this much energy of a gamma photon is enough to expand the universe at an accelerated rate?

Comment: "but we know the most probable reason is dark energy" . How is dark energy the reason?

Answer (score 3):

You need to first define what’s ‘outside’ the universe. Since outside the Big Bang is meaningless hence outside the universe is also meaningless. That’s because space and time started at the big bang.

Here’s another way to think of it:

When the universe expanded, the very ‘fabric’ of space time expanded. During the inflationary period the universe accelerated exponentially. Due to this light hasn’t had the time to travel the entire universe. (It is possible for space time to expand faster than light but matter cannot move faster than light. This is in accordance with general relativity). This problem is also known as the Horizon problem in cosmology. If you look at the universe as a whole it appears to be smooth. But light didn’t have the time to reach every end of the universe then how could other ends of the universe know how smooth to be. This problem is active in the physics community as it hasn’t been solved. Thus if light could not reach the far ends of the universe how could light travel outside the universe.

Hope this helps.

Comment: please explain what is inflationary period of the universe.......

Comment: @C.Jain inflationary period of the universe is a period of time in the universe when it expanded at an exponential rate. The exact cause is unknown at the atomic level is unknown but the theory predicts in a good way the rate. The universe expanded in volume by as much as 10^78 Times more. Without it you cannot account for the fine tuned structure.

Comment: "If you look at the universe as a whole it appears to be smooth". @physics2000 - what does smooth means?

Comment: @C.Jain https://m.esa.int/spaceinimages/Images/2013/03/Planck_CMB see the first photo on the site. What do you see as the most striking thing? If you look overall not on the minute scale but the whole image, it looks so smooth. It looks almost ordered. This is the cosmic microwave background radiation of the universe. Check more on Wikipedia